# Variance of a normal distribution for coin toss.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance

I have difficulties constructing the normal distribution for (20) coin tosses. (Don't ask why, but I never had probability in school.)

> What is the probability of getting at most 12 heads out of 20 tosses?

With the help of Wikipedia, I think that the CDF of a normal distribution gives the answer at $X=12$:

For that I need the mean, which is $10$, and the variance, which is
$$\frac{1}{20}\sum_{k=1}^{20}(k-10)^2=\frac{1}{20}\sum_{k=1}^{9}k^2+\frac{1}{20}\sum_{k=1}^{10}k^2=$$$$\frac{1}{20}\cdot\frac{9(9 + 1)(2\cdot9 + 1)}{6}+\frac{1}{20}\cdot\frac{10(10 + 1)(2\cdot10 + 1)}{6}=\frac{67}{2}$$

Now I tried to look up the normal distribution with mean $10$ and variance $33.5$ on wolframalpha, but at $X=12$ the CDF is much lower $(\sim 0.6352)$ than the result given in the book ($\sim 0.8$). The thing I was most unsure about was the variance, that's why I included it in the title, but maybe something else is wrong, too.

Comment: Why not just use the formula for a binomial distribution to compute your answer? $$P(X \leq 12) = \sum_{r=0}^{12} {20 \choose r}(0.5)^r(0.5)^{20-r}$$

Comment: @Brenton Yeah that's my alternative. But I'd still like to know how to do it this way. Do you know a way to calculate $\sum_{r=0}^{12} {20 \choose r}$ fast?

Comment: You need to start summing from $0$, not $1$. Or easier, $var=20\cdot \frac 1 4=5$. So, including continuity correction, $P(H\le 12)=\Phi(2.5/\sqrt 5))$.

Comment: @A.S. If I start summing from 0, I still don't get 5. But that gives the correct result, thanks.

Comment: There are only 1048576 possibilities here. It shouldn't be too hard to write a computer program to enumerate them and find the answer that way.

Comment: You need to weights $(k-10)^2$ terms by their probabilities ($k=0$ is much less likely than $1/20$ for example). It's much easier to recognize that you have $B(20,\frac 1 2)$ distribution and its variance is $20\cdot \frac 1 2\cdot(1-\frac 1 2)$.

Comment: @A.S. I see now, thank you.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 I know how to do it that way: 0.868412017822266, but thanks :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Point (1): The distribution of heads from flipping a coin is a binomial distribution, *not* a normal distribution. Note that, for example, the former is discrete while the latter is continuous. However: the normal distribution can be used as an *approximation*, since the binomial is numerically much more intensive (esp. by hand calculation).

Point (2): You're correct that your calculation of the variance is way off the reservation -- personally I can't tell what the reference or source for that calculation was. Perhaps that's vaguely in the direction of the variance of rolling a single 20-sided die? (Or maybe one with faces 0 to 20.) The correct variance for this binomial distribution is: $\sigma^2 = np(1-p) = 20(0.5)(0.5) = 5$; i.e., a standard deviation of $\sigma = \sqrt{5} \approx 2.24$.

So, taking an upper limit of $x = 12.5$ (the halfway cutoff between 12 and 13) and standardizing, this gives us a standardized score of $z = (x - \mu)/\sigma = (12.5 - 10)/2.24 = 1.12$. And looking up the associated area on a standard normal curve table gives $\Phi(1.12) = 0.8686$ (with other technology varying a bit for rounding).

As an additional hint, [you can just type this word problem directly into Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=chance%20of%20getting%20at%20most%2012%20heads%20in%2020%20coin%20flips) (and note the "More statistics" button there).